# AppCompat v22: Set default textcolor for TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat

I would like to set a default textcolor in my AppTheme, which should be black (not the default Material Design dark grey). The textColor should be overriden by setting a custom style via android:textAppearance-attribute on a UI-element (e.g. TextView).

**This is my current setup:**

I use AppCompat-Library in my project:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

I defined the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item> <!-- All TextViews should have this color as default text color -->
</style>
```

which is set in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
  android:name=".core.BaseApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Furthermore I defined some styles to change the textAppearance of some TextViews:

```
<style name="App.Heading" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="App.Heading.Highlighted" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Now I have a xml-layout with some TextViews. Some of them should have the default textAppearance (in fact a black text color as defined as android:textColorPrimary in my theme). Some should apply a custom textappearance from my defined styles:

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:text="CUSTOM: App.Heading"
     android:textAppearance="@style/App.Heading" />

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:text="CUSTOM: App.Heading.Highlighted"
     android:textAppearance="@style/App.Heading.Highlighted" />

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:text="Normal Textview with no style"/>
```

The first two TextView apply my defined textAppearance, which is fine. But the last TextView has a dark grey textcolor (Material Design default?) and not a black one. If I set the attribute:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
```

in my AppTheme, all TextViews have a black text color. The textcolor defined in my styles (e.g. App.Heading) is no longer recognized.

So my question is: **How can I set a default textColor for my TextViews, which could be overridden by setting a textAppearance?**

Comment: Christopher; have you gotten any solution?

Comment: @VahidGhadiri Sorry, no direct solution. I used the mentioned workarounds below.

Comment: does it work if you set theme `AppTheme` to these `TextView`s `ViewGroup`.maybe it just lost track what's what. keep me posted

Comment: use android:textColorTertiary option. I have faced similar issue and textColorTertiary solved issue

Answer (score 16):

It is not easy to find the way because there are three styleable `android:textColor` attributes, textColorPrimary textColorSecondary and textColorTertiary, and a lot of attributes for base styles `android:textAppearance` as small medium etc (now deprecated?).

Anyway, about TextView without style, it seems that it refers as default to the `android:textAppearanceSmall` styleable attribute of which value is style `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small` that overrides through `Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small` the `android:textColor` attribute with `?android:attr/textColorTertiary` value.

Then overriding it like the following will work:

```
<item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/black</item>
```

Comment: Thx for this ! Where did you find in the code of Android that TextView uses textAppearanceSmall and not simply textAppearance ?

Comment: I really do not remember , I think I read styles AppCompat in res /values and went for exclusion

Comment: Found it in the Widget.TextView style of the plateform (not in appcompat). Thank you !

Comment: Mine was an empirical method , yours theoretical is better. Thks to you.

Comment: where are you supposed to put the line `<item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/black</item>` in AppTheme?

Comment: exactly in AppTheme as other android:textColor---

Comment: This is exact answer. If we use  android:textColor it will do the same but it will also effect AlertDialog positve and negative button text color in pre lolipop and post lolipop version. It will use  android:textColor

Answer (score 2):

If I remember well, you cannot set the color of the text using the textAppearance. You need to use a style or a theme to achieve this.

Comment: Hmm, the docs says something different. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance: Base text color, typeface, size, and style. -> Or do I misinterpret something?

Comment: Documentation says that that is the base, but after the base there is the style and then the theme. What about creating a style where you define the textColor and the textAppearance, and assign the style to your TextView?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did not know that. If I set the my custom textAppearances as a style, it works. Defining a style as well seems to be a workaround, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Please define following code in style.xml files which are available in v11 ,v14 and v21 folder.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

and use this style for every textview.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid this and would like to use a default. This is only a workaround from my point of view.

Comment: So there is no way to define a global default? I thought the attribute textColorPrimary in my theme should work, but it doesn'nt.

Comment: You have define color in all style.xml file which are available in v14 , v11 and v21 folder

Comment: I already did this. See last section in my question. In this case the textcolor in my custom styles are no longer recognized when using them as textAppearance. I could use the style-attribute, but therefore I would prefer the solution with a custom style for the default behaviour.